# Не отвечает форма ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Делаю аякс отправку формы. Вот код

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ---- Форма -----
    var options = {
        // элемент, который будет обновлен по ответу сервера 
        target: "#output",
        // beforeSubmit: showRequest, // функция, вызываемая перед передачей 
        success: showResponse,
        // функция, вызываемая при получении ответа
        timeout: 100 // тайм-аут
    };

    // привязываем событие submit к форме
    $('#form1').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        // !!! Важно !!! 
        // всегда возвращаем false, чтобы предупредить стандартные
        // действия браузера (переход на страницу form.php) 
        return false;
    });
    // ---- Форма -----
});
```

в файле ответа формы делаю отправку почты и возвращаю ответ об удачной отправке. Если выключить функцию отправки почты, все хорошо работает. Если включаю, пишет

> `POST http://domain.com/form.php Aborted.`

При этом никаких ошибок в php и Apache нет. Не знаю, куда уже копать.

Файл form.php

```
require_once 'class/mail.php'; 
if(!empty($_POST['name']))
{
    $text = $_POST['mes']."Телефон: ".$_POST['tel']." Имя ".$_POST['name']." Компания ".$_POST['kom'];
    if(My_Mail($text))
    {
        $suff = "Спасибо ваше сообщение успешно отправлено";
        echo $suff;
        return 0;
    }else
    {
        echo "Ошибка отправки лота";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Обрывалось по таймауту... долго почту отправляло.